# Probability of x *dependent* events happening in y attempts

Tags: probability, independence

Some statistics were done on the results of 6 members of a youtube group getting drafted on the "good team" and "bad team" for 5 different videos. I'm interested in the probablity of exactly one member getting drafted straight "good team" and another getting all "bad team" - here it is Tobi and Ethan.

It seems to me these draft events are dependent as there *always* has to be 3 members on each team for a given video. The drafting process is as follows: First they pick a random member to put in the good team. Then they pick a random member from the rest to go on the bad team, and so on, alternating between putting a random person into the good/bad team.

I'm not quite sure how to approach this problem as these are not simply independent coin flips. I hope someone can help me with how to approach this. 
Image of drafts linked:

[image: Image of draft results]

Answer (score 1):

This would be complicated, more so since it is possible to have more than one person always good.  So simulation might give a quicker approximation to the answer to your question.

For example the R code (trying $10^5$ times)

```
allgoodorbad <- function(people, size, times){ 
  ingoodteam <- rowSums(replicate(times, (1:people) %in% sample(people,size)))
  c(allgood=sum(ingoodteam == times),  allbad=sum(ingoodteam == 0))
  }

set.seed(2021)
sims <- replicate(10^5, allgoodorbad(6, 3, 5))
table(sims[1,], sims[2,])
```

gives

```
        0     1     2
  0 70009 11770   119
  1 11459  5828   306
  2   128   305    76
```

and that suggests the probability of exactly one member getting drafted straight "good team" and exactly one other getting all "bad team" is about $5.8\%$, while the probability of at least one member getting drafted straight "good team" and at least one other getting all "bad team" is about $6.5\%$.

There is the very small probability that all six are either all good or all bad, of ${{6\choose 3}^{-4}} =0.000625\%$, but this is so unlikely that it did not turn up in the simulation